# Ubuntu Server on IBM x3200 m3

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, bios, ibm

I would like to by an IBM x3200 m3 Server.
Is it possible to install a version of Ubuntu Server on it?
Thank you for your help!

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me its rather dated hardware (2010-ish?), still one might expect Ubuntu to recognize everything. I would suggest to talk to the owner of the box and ask him boot from a Live USB/CD to see what errors may popup.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe an older version of Ubuntu Server?

Comment: I would try Ubuntu Server x64 16.04.2 LTS, I think 17 is too new.